# Please help me convert this sql to LINQ

Tags: linq

```
DECLARE @items table (
    pfid varchar(8),
    timestart datetime,
    timeend   datetime
)

insert INTO @items(pfid,timestart,timeend)
VALUES('123456','12:00 AM','3:00 AM')
,('987654', '2:00 AM', '4:00 PM')
,('492384', '3:00 PM', '9:00 PM')

SELECT * FROM @items a
    INNER JOIN @items b
        ON a.timestart < b.timeend
        AND b.timestart < a.timeend
        AND a.pfid != b.pfid
```

I need the select statement above converted to LINQ.  In my code, I am working with a DataTable, named 'dt'.  My table has three columns just like in the example above, exact same names and populated with this data.

I am struggling to create a LINQ query that will query my DataTable in the same fashion my SQL query is working with the temp table above.  Please assist.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried? show some code to show you've made an effort, and clarify what exactly you're having trouble with?

Comment: Why use a datatable?

Comment: I couldn't accomplish what I wanted using a collection of hashtables....needed somewhere to put the data from the hashtables so I came up with a DataTable.  What is a better alternative?  Thank you for writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something in the line of...i didn't test this but you may have to do Datetime.Parse etc if needed...

```
(from r1 in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
 from r2 in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
 where r1["timestart"] < r2["timeend"] &&  r2["timestart"] < r1["timeend"] && r1["pfid"] != r2["pfid"]
 select new {R1=r1, R2=r2})
```

Comment: This worked!!  Thank you so much.  I worked hard to get the DataTable populated with the contents of several Hashtables so that I could query them...but once I got to the stage of creating the LINQ query I was stumped.  Thank you for helping me!!

Comment: you are welcome...i know someday you will help me :-)